# archlinux in a different HDD

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot, uefi, gpt

I have a PC with a mechanical interrupt in order to enable different hdds and use different OSs. Windows has bee installed with bios legacy and I am trying to install archlinux-uefi.

 At the end of the installation i reboot archlinux and it is all ok, the installation procedure was performed correctly. I shutdown and power on and it is still ok.

When I switch back to Windows (fortunately still working) and then again switch back to archlinux starts the uefi instead of the OS. My impression is it seems the GPT has been modified since regenerating fstab and grub.config files the problem remains and no message is displayed after power on, just the uefi starts, as it does not find GPT.

 Some of you has any idea of what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: "starts the uefi" Um, the UEFI is what loads the OS? It's also what loads the BIOS/MBR bootloader that loads your legacy BIOS-based installation.

Comment: probably I didn't use the proper technical words, sorry, my bad.
I mean the UEFI/BIOS does not find  the OS when the linux-HDD is switch on and windows-HDD is switch off and so starts the classical UEFI/BIOS configuration menu (the one which start after hitting F2, del or whatever key after power on)

Comment: ah, and in that the Linux bootloader is also not found? (in many of these setup interfaces, you can set the boot order for UEFI-compatible bootloaders)

Comment: UEFI forgets UEFI boot entries (or changes to a default) when a drive is disconnected. Better to always keep drive connected or boot using drive or fallback entry, if available. That uses /EFi/Boot/bootx64.efi which is similar to what is on all external UEFI bootable drives.

Comment: at.MarcusMüller no, the UEFI/BIOS does not find anything if after installation I switch to windows and then switch to Unix (of course after power off each time), while it does not has problems when after installation I power off and power on maintaining the switch in the same position. The bootloader order is properly configured (check sata interface number)

at.oldfred so there's no solution? I previous use kalilinux "bios version" and I was capable of switching between the 2 OSs

Comment: hm, I mean you're really using PC style hardware in "creative" ways with your switchover. Usually, UEFI keeps a list of installed bootloaders on internal storage devices, and you can select from that. The firmware might simply not expect the internal devices to be there sometimes, and sometimes not be there. However, usually, this "just works" for external media (i.e., usb drives), which the UEFI can't know about "beforehand". So, can you maybe start the "boot device selection dialog" and select the hard drive which you expect to contain the Linux boot loader?

Comment: (btw., you can check whether there's a FAT partiton with a EFI/boot/bootx64.efi file. That's all that's technically needed for a bootloader to be loaded from UEFI)

Comment: I was reading something about disk and external media, is it possible archlinux assign a  different disk identifier every time the device storage is disconnected? So maybe  change the way GPT references to disk (/dev/disk/by- identifier ) solves this problem? (sorry for using terms non properly, I don't even know if it makes sense)

Comment: My suggestion is that it would be best if you posted your solution as an answer rather than an addition to the question.

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. To mark it as resolved, post an answer and accept it. (You probably have to wait a bit before you can accept your own answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE - now works.

I think is a combination between fstab and bad grub install parameter.

With the following command at installation, now works.

- *genfstab -t PARTLABEL* --> in order to generate fstab based on partitionlabel, and refers to persistent block name (not sure it is necessary)
- *grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=esp --removable --recheck* -->  to grub from a "removable-like" device (since the HDD can be deatached)

  as specified in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Install_Arch_Linux_on_a_removable_medium

  *esp* is the Efi System Partition, I followed the installation guide so is equal to */boot*, since EFI is mounted here

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a system whose UEFI firmware auto-deletes any NVRAM boot variables that refer to disks that are not accessible.

That means, you will have to prepare your UEFI OS's bootloaders for UEFI removable media-style boot.

To fix your current Arch installation, boot from an external media, chroot to the installation, make sure the EFI System Partition (ESP) is mounted in the appropriate location (usually `/boot/efi` or just `/boot`) and run:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=<ESP mountpoint> --removable
```

(replace `<ESP mountpoint>` with the path to where you actually mounted the ESP)

This should install GRUB to `<ESP mountpoint>/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` which is where the UEFI firmware looks for it on removable media or when there are no applicable UEFI NVRAM boot variables to specifically identify the bootloader location.